# How to create irregular shape on phone case?

Tags: boolean-modifier

I'm relatively new to blender and I'm trying to create phone case same as on picture below:

[image]

My problem is that I have no idea how to create the shape of the white part of the case. I started off with cube to create rectangular shape, added boolean modifier and added object to camera lens, displayed the camera lens as Bounds, but it resulted in still having rectangular shape with rough corners instead of cutout with rounded corners as I need. What's the best solution to this? Below i showed what i got, but since it's still a rectangle I can't adjust the corners.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can bevel corners with the shortcut CTRL+Shift+B
[image]

If you want a non-destructive workflow, you can add a bevel modifier with a high angle value. It should work in your case

[image]

This is what I was able to get with a non destructive workflow
[image]

here is the file if you want to take a look
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! Especially for the file, it helps a lot <3 Have a nice day. How did you create the holes in case?

Comment: No problem! I used a plane with a subdivision modifier, and then I instanced a cylinder on each vertex of the plane with geometry nodes. Finally I used a bolean modifier on the white part and used the plane with the cylinder as a cutter

Comment: amazing! thank you again

Comment: Hello, sorry for bothering but I would like to ask how to render this file? Whenever i try to render the image the holes in case are not visible or only few are visible.